# Truncate Article Titles

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I'm looking to have the system truncate any titles appearing on the front end of the website (Basically not directly on the article itself). I'm doing this to keep from ruining formats when my authors *continually refuse* to keep their article titles short, so I'd like to truncate them just to level this all out.

I'm using Joomla's default article editor, so what would I do to enact this kind of change? And where would I place any necessary code?

Comment: You may be able to do this with CSS. Take a look at css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis and the links they suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.joomla.org/API16:JHtmlString/truncate

Try using this function, you will probably need to do a template override for your article listings, override the template for the article listing, use the truncate function to truncate the title of the document.

There is some code samples in the truncate page above.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides